# How do I get the span of a list of vectors from a finite field of prime order

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-fields

I have a list of vectors from a vector space over a finite field of order p for some prime p.  For example:  I have:  {{1,0,1},{0,1,2}} where the vectors are in $\mathbb{F}_3^3$.  I want a list of the 9 vectors which are all the linear combinations of my list.  For example:  from the 2 vectors in the above list I want {{0,0,0},{1,0,1},{2,0,2},{0,2,1},{0,1,2},{1,2,2},{2,1,1},{1,1,0},{2,2,0}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take all possible pairs from your field and use them for linear combinations of your two vectors.

```
pairs = Flatten[Table[Mod[{i, j}, 3], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}], 1];
Mod[pairs . {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}} , 3]
```